# Why does my Firebase query don't return objects that were manually created in the console?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Query 1 works just fine. I create the User objects in the app when users sign up. I see in the console how many objects the User object has.

```
let query1 = ref.child("Users").queryLimited(toFirst: 1000)
query1.observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded) {
    (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

    print(snapshot.children)

}
```

Query 2 does not do anything at all. I don't get errors, nothing I print to the log appears, literally nothing happens. I create the Banner object in the Firebase console.

```
let query2 = ref.child("Banner").queryLimited(toFirst: 1000)
query2.observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded) {
    (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

    print(snapshot.children)

}
```

Is this something to do with security? I simulated the creation of the Banner object as close to the User object as possible.

Comment: well.. who do you call your 2nd query?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code and check if this works:

```
query2.observe(FIRDataEventType.childChanged) {
     (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
      print(snapshot.children)
    }
```